# How to get multiple values from multiple select drop down in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

My code is given below,

```
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="myModelProperty" name="category" (change)="catFilter($event.target.value);hName($event.target.value);" class="form-control">
        <option>Select Cat</option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let type of cat">
            <ng-container *ngIf="type.Record.Pre!=undefined"> 
            <ng-container *ngIf="type.Record.prefname">
            <option [value]="type.Record.pre">{{type.Record.prefname}}</option>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let e of cat">
            <ng-container *ngIf="e!=type">
                <ng-container *ngIf="e.Record.Pre == type.Record.Pre">
                <option [value]="type.Record.subcat">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ e.Record.subcat }}</option>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
    </select>
```

And in my ts file,

```
   catFilter(selectedCat:string){
      this.selectedCat = selectedCat;
   }
```

I want to choose multiple values & get the selected values from the dropdown. Can anybody please tell me how to do this in angular 6? I have followed many links, But they have shown me how to get a value of a single option. But I need to get values of multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

First 
You wrote a wrong *Object key* in `<option [value]="type.Record.pre">{{type.Record.prefname}}</option>` 
as you see `[value]="type.Record.pre"` should be `[value]="type.Record.Pre"`

Second
`[(ngModel)]` is a two way data binding that means when you set the default selection from *Component's TS File* and can get selected values directly from `<select></select>`

i tired to follow your data model and came with this result

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isquyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank you. In stackblitz it is working. But in my code, Im getting only the first option value. Second options are like undefined. Can you please tell me what Im doing wrong? @Ahmed Saied

Comment: My json format is like this,     public cat = [{
    Record: {
        Pre: 1,
        prefname: 'cat 1'
    }
  },
  {
    Record: {
        Pre: 2,
        prefname: 'cat 2',
    }
  },
  {
    Record: {
        Pre: 1,
        prefname: 'cat 2',
        subcat : 'aaa'
    }
  },
  {
    Record: {
        Pre: 2,
        prefname: 'cat 2',
        subcat : 'sss'
    }
  },
  {
    Record: {
        Pre: 3,
        prefname: 'cat 3'
    }
  },
  ];